# Angular 2 does not update the contents of the array in the component

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I am applying filters to a table, using pipes in angular 2, but when I apply the filter the array is not updated with the new value

This is my file with the pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'AgreementPipe',
  pure: false
})
export class AgreementPipe implements PipeTransform {
  tmp = [];

  transform(items: any[], filter: Object): any {
    this.tmp.length = 0;
    if (!items || !filter) {
      return items;
    }
    // return items.filter(item => item.agreement.name.indexOf(filter['name']) !== -1);

    let arr = items.filter(item => item.agreement.name.indexOf(filter['name']) !== -1);
    console.log(arr);
    this.tmp.push(...arr);
    return this.tmp;
  }
}
```

This is my * ngFor

```
<tr *ngFor="let Viability of mf.data | AgreementPipe : agreements ">
```

The filter if it is updated in the HTML view, but when I print the array it does not have the updated data

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: this line `console.log(arr);` print arr to console?

Comment: I'm just checking that the values ​​are updated in the pipe

Comment: okay, comment `if (!items || !filter) {
      return items;
    }` and test